# UnsatisfiedLinkError calling JNI generated by SWIG?

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface, swig

I'm trying to create a C dynamic library that's callable from Java. I've compiled a DLL under [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#compiling_dynamic) to generate the JNI with the following makefile:

```
CC= gcc -mno-cygwin
SWIG= /cygdrive/c/Documents\ and\ Settings/student/Desktop/swigwin-2.0.4/swig.exe -java 
INCLUDE1= -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/include 
INCLUDE2= -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/include/win32

utilities:
    ${SWIG} utilities.i
    ${CC} -c utilities.c utilities_wrap.c ${INCLUDE1} ${INCLUDE2}
    ${CC} -shared utilities.o utilities_wrap.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -o utilities.dll
```

Here are the contents of the SWIG interface file **utilities.i**:

```
/* utilities.i */
%module utilities
%{
#include "driver.h"
%}

extern int get_3711a_fd(char * device);
/* Other prototypes omitted for brevity */
```

I've verified that the methods are being correctly exported from the DLL, and placed *utilities.dll* in both:

1. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
2. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin

I use `System.load(libraryPath)` to load from path **1.** above, with the library file-name included in the path, and catch any `SecurityException` or `UnsatisfiedLinkError` on that call.

The library loads without any exceptions, but calling the library fails with the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
invokeoncomport.utilitiesJNI.get_3711a_fd(Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at invokeoncomport.utilitiesJNI.get_3711a_fd(Native Method)
    at invokeoncomport.utilities.get_3711a_fd(utilities.java:14)
    at invokeoncomport.Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

Comment: Is utilities_wrap.c the wrapper code generated by SWIG?

Comment: Yes it is, and it seems to have the necessary exports; eg. `SWIGEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_utilitiesJNI_get_13711a_1fd(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this section of the SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#using_own_jni_functions), which says:

> The packageName and moduleName must of
>   course be correct else you will get
>   linker errors when the JVM dynamically
>   loads the JNI function.

After looking at `utilities_wrap.c`, I saw my generated JNI method definitions did not contain a package name. To fix this, I added the SWIG [-package command-line option](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_commandline) to the first line of my makefile:

```
swig.exe -java -package invokeoncomport utilities.i
```

My JNI methods definitions now look like the following, and my linking error is fixed!

```
SWIGEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_invokeoncomport_utilitiesJNI_set_13711a_on(...)
```