# Swig C++ to Java UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, g++, swig, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I convert C++ to Java using swig.
I use g++ for creating DLL and compiling.

```
swig -c++ -java -package preprocessor Point.i
g++ -c -std=c++11 Point.cpp Point_wrap.cxx -I E:\ProgramFiles\jdk\include -I E:\ProgramFiles\jdk\include\win32
g++ -shared Point_wrap.o Point.o -o point.dll
```

I don't have any errors while compilation and creating dll.
So when I put generated java files and dll to my project I have an UnsatisfiedLinkError when I create new object. It appears only when I use Windows 8.1 x86. On x64 version everything works fine.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  preprocessor.PointClassJNI.new_Point__SWIG_0()J
at preprocessor.PointClassJNI.new_Point__SWIG_0(Native Method)
at preprocessor.Point.<init>(Point.java:78)
at GUI.FileWorker.fileParser(FileWorker.java:45)
at GUI.MainWindow$2.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:139)
```

This is what swig generates and where error occurs when I create point = new Point();

```
  public Point() {
    this(PointClassJNI.new_Point__SWIG_0(), true);
  }
```

Maybe someone had this problem. I will be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Where do you call System.loadLibrary("point.dll")?

Comment: I call it in static block right before method where I create new object. point.dll located in the root project folder.

Comment: The dll is compiled on 32bit machine ? (maybe you could upload the resulting dll somewhere ?)

Comment: Are the dependencies (the GCC debug crap, libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll) on your path / in the same directory? That would not explain why it works on 64bit, but check it.

Comment: I include tdmGCC\bin to system Path variable, and also I tried compile dll in this folder, where libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll etc. located. Error the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613545/unsatisfiedlinkerror-calling-jni-generated-by-swig?rq=1).
Just need to add -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias to my .bat file when I create dll.

```
swig -c++ -java -package preprocessor Point.i
g++ -c -std=c++11 Point.cpp Point_wrap.cxx -I E:\ProgramFiles\jdk\include -I E:\ProgramFiles\jdk\include\win32
g++ -shared Point_wrap.o Point.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -o point.dll
```

rkapl, thank you for respond!